# SearchResponse of Elasticsearch java high level rest client is bringing an empty set of values as result

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch Java rest high level client in my spring boot application. I have successfully indexed the data using BulkRequest. But when I want to implement search I am unable to do so. I am using SearchRequest to build a search query. In my QueryBuilders I am using multiMatchQuery to search for a keyword on multiple fileds. Below is the attached code of what I am trying :-

```
public List<POJOClass> searchByKeyword(String keyword) throws IOException {

  SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("indexName");
  searchRequest.types("indexType");
  SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();      
  QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(keyword)
          .field("field1")
          .field("field2")
          .field("field3")
          .field("field4");         
  searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);      
  searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

  SearchResponse searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);    

  SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
  SearchHit[] searchHits = hits.getHits();
  List<POJOClass> list= new ArrayList<>();      
  for(SearchHit hit : searchHits) {

        list.add(objectMapper.convertValue(hit.getSourceAsMap(), POJOClass.class));
      }     
  return list;
  }
```

Following is the query formed by QueryBuilder, when I call the controller method passing a keyword:-

```
  curl -XGET "127.0.0.1:9193/search?keyword=KEYWORD"


 {
  "multi_match" : {
   "query" : "KEYWORD",
    "fields" : [
     "field1^1.0",
     "field2^1.0",
     "field3^1.0",
     "field4^1.0",
    ],
  "type" : "best_fields",
  "operator" : "OR",
  "slop" : 0,
  "prefix_length" : 0,
  "max_expansions" : 50,
  "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
  "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
  "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
  "boost" : 1.0
 }
}
```

After calling this method through a REST controller, the SearchResponse method returns an empty set of array. Following is the result:-

```
{"took":74,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

While when I hit query using simple curl by passing id it returns the result. For ex.-

```
 curl -XGET 127.0.0.1:9200/indexName/indexType/id
```

Comment: Does any of the fields [field1,field2,field3,field4] contains "KEYWORD" in uppercase?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal yes field2 contains "KEYWORD" in uppercase. I have also tried with field1, which is nothing but the id in which the documents are indexed in elasticsearch.

Comment: @jaspreetchahal Actually the real keyword is alphanumeric, For ex. - "DEMO1".

Comment: Hey! generally its better to help you when u provide the index mapping and an example document that should be matched by the query and that is present in the index. thanks!